# why is this android button transparent?

Tags: android-layout

I have a static button in an activity view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layout_record"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_review"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Review" 
        android:color="#e5e5e5"
        android:alpha="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Later some code will insert a SurfaceView derived class behind the button (doing something like: getViewById("layoutRecord".addChild(surfaceView, 0))

The problem is the button is transparent and hard to see, even though I am setting the color and alpha of the button.  I believe I have the controls stacked in the right order because if I call addChild(surfaceView,1) then the surfaceView completely hides the button.

Why is the button still transparent?

Comment: Try to use background instead Color property

Answer (score 0):

android:color="#e5e5e5" this property not there in Button only textColor,backgrount etc., not in color

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/layout_record"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_review"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Review" 
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
    android:alpha="1" />
```